# How to disable compilation of a LOCAL_MODULE in Android.mk?

Tags: android, linux, build

I would like to ignore compiling a LOCAL_MODULE for the time being as it is not important and move forward using Android.mk.
Is there a way to do this?

I know I could just delete the entire folder and move forward and replace it whenever required but I feel there may be a way to do it using Android.mk. I just cant find a way to google it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the .c, .cpp file from LOCAL_SRC_FILES in Android.mk which you don't want to compile. I have not tried this but, from what I read about Android.mk and LOCAL_SRC_FILES, this should help you not compile the files you don't want to.